# how to create a Window WIN32?

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface

I just wondering how Windows create this window?

[image: Windows Security Authentication]

I mean what styles applied to that window, I just want these styles on my project.

As info I use MS Visual C++ 2008.

Thanks

Comment: It is just a plain dialog, same styling as any dialog frame gets.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for reply, is it created using `CreateDialog()` or `CreateWindow()`? And how can I make a separate region, I mean white for credentials input and gray for button? Thanks

Comment: All those are windows. You don't create separate regions, but you add windows which have a cetain style or "system class" (read documentation of `CreateWindow`). The text box is a window, and the buttons are windows. They're all created with `hWndParent` being the handle you got from creating the first window (which looks like `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` style).

Comment: It's possible to do that by loading a resource (which you have to generate first, of course -- presumably with a resource editor) as well. But for those 4 controls, it's hardly worth the trouble.

Comment: @Damon: So it is just window over window? If I corerct, I guess the white region is a child control that acts as a container? (may be static control?) And what about the blue region? Is it an ownerdraw button? I mean, it can be clicked right? Thanks

Comment: They're child windows, so window-in-window, not window-over-window. The white regions is likely a borderless window, and the blue one is likely a window with a thin border, but there is no way to know for sure from merely looking at an image.

Comment: Could it be a 'Task Dialog'?

Comment: @all: Although my design was not so good, I finally get it works and I satisfied enough with [these](https://hostr.co/l7Xn2bEusllx) result. Here is my [source](https://hostr.co/uUnf9NoKSlGT). If you have any ideas or suggestion, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way! There's no public API for using "the Windows 8 style", or the style of any other release. You'll just have to replicate it by hand, comparing it pixel-for-pixel against a screenshot. Then update your application with the next release of Windows!

Because they change the metrics of these sorts of dialogs with each release, they can't produce a public library for "system-themed dialogs", because Microsoft would then be unable to change the design for fear of breaking someone's application that maybe uses a bit too much text, for example.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm sorry for being unclear, but "the style" I mentioned before was Window Style passed to `CreateWindow()` or another similiar thing used to create separate region: white for credentials input and gray for buttons. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: -1 for uninformed opinion. For those interested: [Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773187.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable Actually, I don't think that's what the OP is looking for. I'm well aware that you can get styled buttons and controls, but I'm not aware of any way to get a complete dialog (with fonts and colours matching the system dialog, with the correct placement of the horizontal rule, the grey area at the bottom, and so on). If you know of a way to create native-looking *dialogs* (not just controls), then please post a proper answer. For the reason given though (changing metrics across releases) I don't think there is a public library for this. -1 for uninformed comment.

Comment: Dialogs and layouts are - and have been for the past 30 years - described through dialog resources. Sizes are specified in DLUs so that you don't have to worry about changes in font metrics. You create a dialog from resource by using [`CreateDialogIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645436.aspx). Retrieving the dialog template resource is no different from retrieving any other resource from a binary image.

Comment: @IInspectable We're still talking at cross-purposes. He's describing (I think) creating a dialog matching the current Windows style. There is no ready-made dialog resource - that's the whole point. Where do you propose to get that pale blue background colour from - it's different on Vista and Win 8! As far as I'm aware, the styling has to be hardcoded into your application. Could you give an example of an API that would return the right colour, or draw a custom title using the same style as "Save credentials" in his example?

Comment: [`GetSysColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724371.aspx)? [`DrawThemeBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773289.aspx)? Or even just [`CreateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679.aspx), which does the right thing already. You should seriously consider **not** answering [winapi] questions - your reputation score may be misleading.

Comment: @IInspectable Please, don't be rude. Again, I think we're still at cross-purposes. (I may be being misleading -- you're probably right that the Button theme data is being used for the center portion of this dialog. Oops.) In general though, DrawThemeBackground is for styling controls - it won't solve the problem of getting a matching title -- unless the right information is deeply hidden undocumented somewhere in AeroStyles.xml. I've just written a test app to check (giving you the benefit of the doubt!) but it doesn't appear that the colour of that title text is one of the GetSysColor values.

Comment: My previous comment wasn't meant to be rude. It's just somewhat unnerving to see you answer a [winapi] question without being even remotely familiar with dialog templates, the dialog manager, the window manager and how these components interact. The solution is simple: Find the dialog template resource, load the resource, have Windows construct a dialog based on that template. No requirement to do anything special, like figuring out colors, fonts, or control spacing.

Comment: @all: Although my design was not so good, I finally get it works and I satisfied enough with [these](https://hostr.co/l7Xn2bEusllx) result. Here is my [source](https://hostr.co/uUnf9NoKSlGT). If you have any ideas or suggestion, please let me know. Thanks